# Can't see a specific folder as un-staged although it is there

Tags: git, bitbucket

Newbie to git - I've cloned a bitBucket (git protocol repository) repository to my local workspace - it is now a local repository, then I copied files to this folder. Now - when trying to see all the unstaged files using the command:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

I see some folders and files, but a specific folder (src) is not there although I can see it in the file system and when ls the parent folder. I've made also the .gitignore file to be empty.
What could be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
> ```

does not list *unstaged* files.  It lists *untracked* files, minus those marked as "don't complain about these" in `.gitignore` and similar exclusion files.

*Unstaged* files is a notion peculiar to `git status`.  A file is *unstaged*, in `git status` output, if the copy of the file that is in the *index*<sup>1</sup> is different from the copy that is in your work-tree.

To get a list of file names that differ between the index copy and the work-tree copy, use `git diff` with no additional commit or `--cached` arguments, and the `--name-only` or `--name-status` argument that tells Git to show only the names (and optionally, status-letter-codes) of the result of running the differencing engine.  Note that `git status` runs the engine with rename detection turned on and set at 50% (this is not configurable), while `git diff` runs it in whatever way you have configured it, or as specified by additional command line arguments.<sup>2</sup>

(Note that `git status` runs *two* `git diff --name-status`-es internally.  The first compares `HEAD` to the index.  To do this with the `git diff` command, run `git diff --cached --name-status`.  Whatever files are listed here are those that `git status` will call *staged for commit*.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The terms *index*, *staging area*, and (rarely these days) *cache* all refer to the same thing in Git.  The index has a copy of every file that is going to be in the *next* commit.  Files that are in the index are, by definition, tracked, so they will not be in `git ls-files --others` output.

<sup>2</sup>See `diff.renames` in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).  If you have not configured this setting, the default is `false` in Git versions predating 2.9 and `true` in Git 2.9 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the target folder I wanted to see in order to upload, was with lots of sub-directories, but all of them were empty, so, as definition - GIT not list it as relevant for commit